# Angular2: Error in inline template

Tags: angular

I'm passing a component as a directive into another component to use in that component's template like so, but I am getting an `Error in inline template`, which is pretty vague, but it's pointing me to the directive.  So I'm no sure if I'm instantiating it correctly in the actually component itself.

**message-list.ts**

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {Message} from './message';
import {MessageModal} from './message';

@Component({
  selector: 'message-list',
  template: require('./message-list.html'),
  styles: [require('./message-list.css')],
  directives: [MessageModal]
})

export class MessageList {
  @Input()
  messages: Message[];
}
```

**message-list.html**

```
<div class="messages">
  <table class="table table-striped" style="width:75%">
    <tr *ngFor="let item of messages">
      <td><message-modal messageInput="{{item.message}}"></message-modal></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

`MessageModal` takes an input, `messageInput`, and `message` is also property of `Message`.  The error is in line 4 of **message-list.html** with the `<message-modal>` directive.  What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are taking `messageInput` as input of message-modal and you are getting in the .ts file via
`@Input messages`  make some changes like this :-

```
<div class="messages">
  <table class="table table-striped" style="width:75%">
    <tr *ngFor="let item of messages">
      <td><message-modal [messageInput]="item.message"></message-modal></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>


export class MessageList {
  @Input() messageInput: any
  messages: Message[];
  constructor(){
   console.log(this.messageInput);
  }
}
```

For more Refer you can see here working example of @input

<kbd>[Working Example of @Input](http://plnkr.co/edit/AiDiNl8SrSKIwDUYWl50?p=preview)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your `@Input` property. `MessageList` component doesn't have any input from its parent. But `message-modal` has from its parent called `MessageList`. So there is no point of using @Input in `MessageList`.

```
export class MessageList {
  @Input()                    
// dont require as its parent doesn't send any data I guess.

  messages: Message[];        
// dont require.still as you are using messages as an array I don't know how'd you get its value.
}
```

This below code would be required later,

```
export class MessageModal{ 
  @Input() messageInput: any;
}
```